# browser cache emulation in jmeter?

Tags: apache, testing, browser, automated-tests, jmeter

Running some user-load tests with jmeter, and noticed that for each page load after the first load, the load sizes are similar. This leads me to believe that jmeter's simulation does not use browser cache emulation (e.g. the caching of css and javascript). **Anyone know of a method for emulating browser cache in jmeter?**

Comment: Of note, JMETER doesn't download dependent files unless you specify to download all content.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try adding the Config Element `HTTP Cache Manager` introduced in JMeter v2.3.2

An example is here:

http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cache_Manager

Comment: how can I know that the cache manager is actually working (i.e. that resources are really cached)?